# Trouble retrieving JSON data within a Ul class

Tags: php, json

I have pulled some JSON data into a web page with php. It is a 'Content' property that contains several Paragraphs within p tags, URL's for images etc. The content display however stops short right before it reaches the last section of this property that starts with a  HTML  tag with a class ie:

```
<ul class=\"social-link-lists\">
```

within this are the `<li></li>` tags that show in the chrome console some link. text

It seems strange that I can get this content from the 'Content' JSON property only up to this point. Is this something to do with the  class

using the below php line to pull in the Content property which displays all up to the  tag

```
<?php echo $post->content; ?>
```

Comment: Can you please specify the content which you want to parse and expected out?

Comment: {
  "type": "post",
  "content": "<P> content here</p> <ul class=\"social-links\"> text here<li>" can display paragraph but not ul

Comment: Please post the method or statement used to decode the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are escaping the  class (social-links)'s double quotes thus it stops after the end of your p tag.

You might need to remove the forward slash in your  class so that it can also read your  tag as well.

Example: (Reference)
(PHP)

```
$sHtmlTag = '';
$sHtmlTag .= '<ul class="social-link">';
$sHtmlTag .= 'children of this tag';
echo json_decode($sHtmlTag, true);
```

Hope this helps for your case

**Edit:**
Since you are retrieving your [json] on a certain third party library and you might only need to get the [html] tag on your [json], You can assign this variable in your [view] or [template] page (e.g home_page.php) like this

```
$sJsonString = '{"type": "post", "content": "<P> content here</p> <ul class=\"social-links\"> text here<li>"}'; //assuming this is the expected json result
$aJsonDecode = json_decode($sJsonString, true);

$sHtmlTag = '';
foreach ($aJsonDecode as $sKeys => $sValues) {
    if ($sKeys === 'content') {
        $sHtmlTag .= $aJsonDecode['content'];
    }
}

echo $sHtmlTag;
```

Comment: thanks, but what do do if I can't edit the JSON. Its part of an API

Comment: Noted. Can you update the question and add the code for retrieving that api from PHP then call it on your JS?

Comment: hi have updated, let me know if you need more. thanks